# How can i manage layout file in tabbed activity in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

**Explanation:**

I took a tabbed activity while i was created my project. In which there is only single layout file for all the fragments in viewpager.I want to set the different layout for different fragment and add tabbed dynamically with dynamic fragment.

Suppose, I have size like 5 then five tab will be created,if i have 2 than it will create two tab.

Here is my MainActivity.java in which inner class also

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    public ViewPager mViewPager;

    String[] title={"SHOES","BAG","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE","TEN"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter.noOfFragment(10);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter.addPageTitle(title);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        int val=0;
        List<String> pageTitle=new ArrayList<>();
        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return val;

        }

        public void addPageTitle(String[] title){
            for(int i=0;i<title.length;i++){
                pageTitle.add(title[i]);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return pageTitle.get(position);
        }
        public void noOfFragment(int size){
            val=size;
        }
    }
}
```

In above code i already created a dynamic tab.I want to separate the layout for each tab.

Please, help me to solve out.

Comment: Create different fragments and return relevant fragments in getItem function of the adapter based on the position. You are returning one fragment for all tabs obviously they will have same layout.

Comment: okay that's fine but i don't know how many fragments are there. it is dynamic then how may times i return the fragments>

Comment: I tied more using switch case in getItem() method but at runtime i know how many fragment are there. note this condition and tell me.

Comment: Then ideally the maximum possible fragments should be known before hand and every item should have an indication of which fragment to load for that item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should create a fragment for each view and set the view on onViewChanged

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_VIEW, container, false);
}
```

and you should create your custom adapter which will look like this

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<Fragment> fragments;
    List<String> titles;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments, List<String> titles) {
        super(fm);

        this.fragments = fragments;
        this.titles = titles;

    } 


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return titles.get(position);
    }
}
```

then your activity you should create list of fragments and pass it to the adapter

```
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentList, titleList);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    TabLayout tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```